# Export functions from a static linked library to another program

Tags: c, windows, dll

I have a DLL1.dll that has staticly linked against openssl.lib. I have packaged all of the OpenSSL functionality into this DLL1.dll.

This DLL1.dll will end up loading another DLL2.dll. This new DLL2.dll will need to use some of the OpenSSL functionality. Instead of packaging the OpenSSL into DLL2.dll, can I use the functionality through DLL1.dll since it has it?

Comment: As long as you don’t explicitly name “OpenSSL.dll” as a dependency in your code for DLL2, it shouldn’t be a problem

Comment: I am including OpenSSL.lib basically into my function.